# How to expose API documentation in Anypoint Studio

Tags: anypoint-studio, raml

I have set up a RAML API on Anypoint studio and the Mock is working. How can I expose the documentation I see in the Console on a Web page so that other people can see it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you design RAML specs for your API and and deploy the spec as a part of Mule application, you will see the documentation part in the console.
To make it independent, you can publish it as a part of PDF or HTML.
You can use [RAML2HTML](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html) or [ramlo](https://github.com/PGSSoft/ramlo) for doing it.
You can also use [raml2md](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2md)output a Markdown file. From there, you can easily generate a PDF with [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to export the documentation as PDF.
ref:- http://forums.raml.org/t/exporting-raml-documentation/1043

You can also refer for your issue :- http://forums.raml.org/t/generating-documentation-from-raml-spec/165/3